# Triangle inequality with complex analysis

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, triangles

[image]

Hi guys, I've calculated the first part, but I don't understand how it is related with triangle inequality. Can someone help？Thanks!

Comment: In this context, the triangle inequality says that the modulus of the first integral is less than or equal to the second integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, parametrize the $\{|z| = 1\}$ by $z = e^{i\theta}$. Then the first integral becomes
\begin{align}
\int_{|z|=1} (z-1)\ dz = \int^{2\pi}_0 (e^{i\theta}-1)ie^{i\theta}\ d\theta = 0.
\end{align}
For the second integral, we have
\begin{align}
\int_{|z|=1} |z-1||dz| = \int^{2\pi}_0 |e^{i\theta}-1| dt = \int^{2\pi}_0 |\cos\theta-1 + i\sin\theta|\ dt = \int^{2\pi}_0 \sqrt{(1-\cos\theta)^2+\sin^2\theta}\ d\theta  = \int^{2\pi}_0\sqrt{2-2\cos\theta}\ d\theta = 2\int^{2\pi}_0 |\sin(\theta/2)|\ d\theta = 8.
\end{align}
Indeed, we have the triangle inequality
\begin{align}
\left|\int_{|z|=1}(z-1)\ dz\right| \leq \int_{|z|=1} |z-1||dz|.
\end{align}